# time domain reflectometer determining impedance

Tags: tdr

Lets say I have a 1km long transmission line with a characteristic impedance of 50ohm. With a pulse generator I inject a really long pulse (30µs) the pulse generators termination is also 50 ohm. The response will look like the image below

T[image]

So the amplitude U/2 of the reflections is because of the voltage divider formed by the two 50 ohm impedances. When using a signal generator with a known resistance (impedance) we should be able to calculate the impedance of any cable by the amplitudes of the reflections. Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *When using a signal generator with a known resistance (impedance) we
> should be able to calculate the impedance of any cable by the
> amplitudes of the reflections. Is my assumption correct?*

It's a little bit easier than that - you don't need to wait for the reflection; at the point you apply the signal (50 Ω source), it is the voltage instantly developed at the cable that determines the impedance. For instance, if your pulse is 1 volt and has a source impedance of 50 Ω and, it connects to a 100 Ω cable, the voltage seen at the cable is: -

$$V_{CABLE} = 1\text{ volt}\cdot \dfrac{100}{100 + 50} = 0.6667\text{ volts}$$

If the cable were 50 Ω impedance then the peak voltage is 0.5 volts.

Comment: But this assumes that the impedance of the cable is a real value?

Comment: @Yoomo If you are using pulses then this is going to be the case. The characteristic impedance will be \$\sqrt{L/C}\$ and that will be resistive above 1 Mohm.

Comment: So with your formula I can calculate the impedance of the cable, when I am using either a pulse or a DC voltage?

Comment: @Yoomo use a pulse and pretty much after applying that pulse (via a resistor) look at the magnitude at the cable end where you apply the pulse. If the cable is short then you might get a reflection coming back too quickly and it screws up the measurement of course.

Comment: I am a bit confused. When I use a long square wave pulse like above the impedance will be a real value and can be calculated like this Vcable=1 volt⋅(100/150)?

Comment: At the instant the pulse is applied, the potential divider formed by the source impedance and the cable's characteristic impedance is created. It's instant so, if you measure after 1 ns or 10 ns or 100 ns or 1 us, you will get the same result (providing the cable is long enough so that far end reflections are avoided during the measurement period).